# redirect containing + is not being encoded properly by visual studio

Tags: performance, visualstudio

I'm currently trying to create a performance test in Visual Studio 2013 for an older web application with numerous redirects.  One of these redirects contains a url with a `+` in it.

```
<h2>Object moved to <a href="%2fPage.aspx%3fname%3dLYNDON+VROOMAN%26type%3dMyType">here</a>.</h2>
```

When Visual Studio attempts to run the web performance test and follows the redirect, it attempts to go to `/Page.aspx?name=LYNDON VROOMAN&TYPE=MyType` which of course returns a 400.  The redirect, of course, is also not appearing in the recording.

I don't normally run performance tests on web sites with a GUI.  I've tried added an HTMLEncoded flag to every parameter, and tried generating code and adding a replace to any of the strings that I can see.

I'm sure that it's something small that I'm missing, but, I'm not seeing it and my searches for information are coming back fruitless.

Comment: I think you are trying to go inside login during load testing. Do you?

Comment: nope, there's no login here.  The name is pulled in the backend via a call to another service.

Comment: If there is no authentication then it should not show that "Object moved" to error.

Comment: Hmm.  I'll have to see if there's something that I'm not seeing right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had got the same issue with web performance test in Visual Studio 2013.
Some redirects in my application contains a white space in their url

```
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/Error/SubErr.aspx?GROUP=MED SH&amp;USER=DAVID GOUPIL">here</a>.</h2>
```

When visual studio attempts this redirect, the web test returns a Bad request.

I finally use a [WebTestPlugin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243191.aspx) to encode each query string parameters before each requests

```
public override void PreRequest(object sender, PreRequestEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var queryStringParam in e.Request.QueryStringParameters)
        queryStringParam.UrlEncode = true;
}
```

And add this event to the `PreRequest` event on `MyWebTest`.

```
private MyWebTestPlugin myPlugin = new MyWebTestPlugin();     
public MyWebTest()
{
    this.PreAuthenticate = true;
    this.Proxy = "default";
    this.PreRequest += this.myPlugin.PreRequest;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Reading other SE questions I think indeed the + symbol will also be encoded correctly when using urlEncode instead of HTMLEncode. Not sure the webtestplugin is needed, also have a look at HttpServerUtility class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx